# Android Version 7.0 not able to read the sdcard cid number

Tags: android

After upgrade to android 7.0, I am not able to read the sdcard cid number. 
I have used following code to read the cid number.

```
public static String getSdCardCID()
{
String memBlk = "";
String sd_cid = "";
try 
        {
File file = new File("/sys/block/mmcblk1");
if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) 
{
memBlk = "mmcblk1";
Process cmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /sys/block/"+memBlk+"/device/cid");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmd.getInputStream()));
sd_cid = br.readLine();
} 
else 
{
//System.out.println("not a directory");
//memBlk = "mmcblk0";
}
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
sd_cid = "";
}
return sd_cid;
}
```

Comment: Yes above Android 6,  `device` is not readable

Comment: How i can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Samsung Knox? After Knox ver.2.6, developer cannot access that path.

Comment: No. Am using Moto G(4), Which is Nougat OS(7.0).

Comment: OK, I'm not sure but, you could possibly access the path with NDK.